# How to calculate the average of the same column (with same name) in 100s different csv files with part of file name in common?

Tags: r, dataframe, csv, import, mean

I have a bunch of csv files that are structured like this:

```
df <- data.frame (first_column  = c(3, 2, 6, 7),
                  second_column = c(7, 5, 1, 8))
```

All the csv files have a name like

```
"type1_1.csv"
"type1_2.csv"
...
"type2_1.csv"
"type2_2.csv"
...
```

Each of these csv's have `first_column` and `second_column`. What I want is to create a new dataframe that looks like this:

```
# name        meanofsecond_column
# type1_1     5.25
# ...
```

What I started doing already, was to individually write out each:

```
type1_1 <- read_csv("type1_1.csv")
type1_1mean <- mean(type1_1$second_column)
...
df <- data.frame (name  = c(type1_1, type1_2...),
                  meanofsecondcolumn = c(type1_1mean, type1_2mean...))
```

However, since there are more than 100 csv files, this method is not very efficient or clean. How can I make it more condensed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# path where your csv files are (here current working directory)
CSV_FOLDER <- "."

# list all csv files in given directory
# second parameter is a regex meaning ends with .csv
# third parameter make function return file names with path
csv_files <- list.files(CSV_FOLDER, "\\.csv$", full.names=TRUE)

# apply given function on each file and collect results in a list
res <- lapply(csv_files, function(csv_file) {
  # read current file
  tmp <- readr::read_csv(csv_file)

  # build a data.frame from filename (without path) and mean of second column
  return(data.frame(
    name = basename(csv_file),
    meanofsecondcolumn = mean(tmp$second_column)
  ))
})

# rbind all single line data.frames in a single data.frame
res <- do.call("rbind", res)
```

Comment: Thank you for the thorough response `Error in do.call(rbind(res)) : 
  argument "args" is missing, with no default` I get this error.

Comment: My fault, fixed :-)

Comment: That fixed that problem, but now I get error: `Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote, : 
duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed`. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Maybe because you are using `read_csv` from `readr` package. Replace `read.csv` with `read_csv` and if it worked with your original code it should work with this one. Next time you ask a question, it's better to include a sample file so as we can try the code on it otherwise we can only guess and provide a one-fit-all kind of answer.

Comment: Yes, replacing read.csv with read_csv worked! For another time, what is a good way to attach a sample file?

Comment: Typically, this is done when a file has already been read in as an R object, the `dput(head(object), n = sufficient_data)`, and the resulting `structure(...)` is copy from your local and pasted above as data, between three backtics, three above, three below. Will have to head scratch a little on 'a file', though in pinch people provide links. `dput(` is safer as you can see what you're getting.

Comment: @VictorNielsen If my answer solved your question, would you mind accept it (check mark near my answer)

Comment: Yes sorry, was getting some other errors, so was still testing it, but it works now!